# React Native fetch API is is not working on Android

Tags: android, react-native, fetch-api

I am beginner a React Native development. I have developed my first React Native application and launched in both Android and iOS version.

In the app I am using fetch API to communicate with the server. App is working fine and getting response from fetch API in iOS version. And it's also working good in Android version if the device is connected to speed network connection(like WiFi,4G..).

But if the device is connected low network connection then the fetch API is not returning any values(getting "Network connection failed" error) in Android version of the app. But in the same connection other apps are working fine which are installed in the same device.

I am using

```
react-native-cli: version 2.0.1
react-native: version 0.55.4
babel-preset-react-native: version 4.0.0,
Android compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion 23.0.1
```

Here is my fetch API code

```
getStudentList() {
var UrlDetails = URLDetails.getURLDetails();
return fetch(UrlDetails.SERVER_NAME + UrlDetails.GET_STUDENT_DETAILS_LIST_URL + 'student_id=1')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    let ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });
    let isAllSet = responseJson.error;
    if (!isAllSet) {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson.student),
        isAllSetToShow: isAllSet,
      }, function () {
        activity_log = "received student details";
        this.updateDeviceLog();
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        isAllSetToShow: isAllSet,
      }, function () {
        activity_log = "received response no student details";
        this.updateDeviceLog();
      });
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    activity_log = JSON.stringify(error);
    Alert.alert('Alert',"Please check your internet connection!");
    this.updateDeviceLog();
  });
```

}

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Did you have any success yet? I'm getting "Network request failed" on android with fetch, but it is working on iOS.

Comment: @mediaguru not yet. Still facing the issue

Comment: I ended up using axios, which worked for my issue. My issue isn't quite the same as yours but in case it helps you could try axios.